# ValueError for comparing value from a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I was comparing each value from a matrix (created using NumPy) with the value of a variable. But I keep getting this error:

> File "main.py", line 63, in findClusters
>       if(val<=nearest): ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried printing out the value and its not an array, but a float value. When I gave all(val), the error is "float is not iterable" Whats wrong with my code?

```
for i in range(0,count):
    nearest = 99999.99
    for ctr in center:
        val = mtrx.item((ctr,i))
        if(val<=nearest):
            nearest = mtrx[ctr][i]
            centerassign = ctr
```

Comment: Try with `if val.all() <= nearest:`

Comment: Then I get "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'all'"

Comment: I ain't a numpy expert, but why do you use simple indexing in `nearest = mtrx[ctr][i]` and not in `val = mtrx.item((ctr,i))`?

Comment: I was using simple indexing at first, but then I though that might be the error when comparing and changed it. I get the same error either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `val` and `nearest`.  One or the other, or both is an array (or numpy matrix).  The result of the comparison is then an array - multivalued.  But the Python `if` requires one boolean value.

Look at the Related sidebar for numerous SO questions about the `ValueERROr, The truth value ...`.

Initially `nearest` is scalar, but on later loops it is set to: `mtrx[ctr][i]`

Assuming `mtrx` is `np.matrix`, beware that indexing operations may still return a 2d array, a matrix.

Use `mtrx[ctr,i]` if you want to select an item from a matrix.  Don't use the sequential brackets (`[][]`) - unless you clearly understand what they are doing.

Comment: I tried giving all() to both val and nearest and the error becomes - 'float' object has no attribute 'all'. Therefore, both of them must be float objects and not arrays. I then tried printing out the values, and I cannot see any arrays in the output.

Comment: Like I said, 1st time around `nearest` is float; you need to check the 2nd iteration.